# How to build MinGW-W64 compiler toolchain from source for Windows platform

Tags: windows, compiler-construction, mingw, mingw-w64

I need to modify some internal MinGW library sources to fix one issue with it and I couldn't find any recent documentation or tutorial on How to build from source MinGW-W64 compiler toolchain for Windows. Could you please point me to a fairly recent (not outdated) documentation explaining step-by-stem how to do this? Thank you!